# NetBeans: No suitable Deployment Server is defined for the project or globally

Tags: netbeans, deployment, glassfish

When I try to deploy my Glassfish project in Netbeans (right-click -> run), I get:

```
No suitable Deployment Server is defined for the project or globally
```

**SOLUTION:** As it turned out, this was due to the fact that I had multiple Glassfish processes running. I deleted all the extras and my project deployment worked.