# Netbeans 11.2: No suitable Deployment Server is defined for the project or globally

Tags: netbeans, deployment, glassfish

I installed Netbeans 11.2 IDE on my Mac. Under Services -> Servers I added GlassFish Server as a server.

Then I opened a maven project. I could "clean and build" it. Then I wanted to run it but this resulted in the following error message:

```
No suitable Deployment Server is defined for the project or globally.
```

I guess this has something to do with the following: there is a window in Netbeans called "Output - Java DB Database Process" and when I started the GlassFish Server the window showed me this message:

```
Sat Feb 08 18:02:45 CET 2020 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Sat Feb 08 18:02:46 CET 2020 : Could not listen on port 1527 on host localhost: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
```

I used the following command to check which process was using port 1527:

```
sudo lsof -n -i :1527 | grep LISTEN
```

This resulted in the following output (note: I removed the real username and the real IP address)

```
java    6722 <user>   36u  IPv6 <IP Address>      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:tlisrv (LISTEN)
```

Since this is a java process I don't want to just kill it.

What should I do?

---

P.S.:

The version of the GlassFish Server is 5.1.0, see Screenshot:

[image]

---

P.P.S.: this question didn't help me: 
[NetBeans: No suitable Deployment Server is defined for the project or globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57914196/netbeans-no-suitable-deployment-server-is-defined-for-the-project-or-globally)

---

P.P.P.S.: the server log says - among other things - the following:

```
Context path from ServletContext:  differs from path from bundle: /|#]
```

Here's a screenshot of the log:

[image]

---

P.P.P.P.S:

the content of the file nb-configuration.xml is the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-shared-configuration>
    <properties xmlns="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/maven-properties-data/1">
        <org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_j2eeVersion>1.7-web</org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_j2eeVersion>
        <org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server>gfv3ee6</org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server>
    </properties>
</project-shared-configuration>
```

Comment: Could you provide more detail? What type of project do you run? What type of packaging your project has? (war, ear)? Could you share the content of the nb-configuration.xml file? After you added the Glassfish Server the error "No suitable Deployment Server.."  still exists in logs?

Comment: @Dmitry.M: it's a java web project, the packaging type is .war (although I don't think this is relevant here because I just want to run the app locally) ... the rest of your questions is answered in my updated post ... I also found the likely cause for the problem (see my updated post) - but I now don't know how to solve that other problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For glassfish 5.1 you should change this parameters in **nb-configuration.xml**

- netbeans_2e_hint_2e_j2eeVersion
- netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server

Try fist changing **gfv3ee6**  to **gfv5ee8** and then change **1.7-web** to **1.8-web**

For me worked this config:

```
<properties xmlns="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/maven-properties-data/1">
    <org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_j2eeVersion>1.8-web</org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_j2eeVersion>
    <org-netbeans-modules-maven-jaxws.rest_2e_config_2e_type>ide</org-netbeans-modules-maven-jaxws.rest_2e_config_2e_type>
    <org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server>gfv5ee8</org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server>
</properties>
```

It should resolve this error:

```
No suitable Deployment Server is defined for the project or globally.
```

As for

```
Context path from ServletContext:  differs from path from bundle: /|#
```

error try to close (or kill, including NetBeans itself) all java processes and start NetBeans again and run the project. It looks like your project was deployed to a different instance of glassfish (the previous version?).

I suppose you shouldn't worry about [these messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23547916/5681468):

```
Sat Feb 08 18:02:45 CET 2020 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Sat Feb 08 18:02:46 CET 2020 : Could not listen on port 1527 on host localhost: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
```

unless it indeed because of the previous instances of glassfish. In such a case just stop the previous instance or kill it.

Comment: does not work. I have all set as you suggest   `1.8-web` and `gfv5ee8` set but still does not work. Here I give question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64920939/no-suitable-deployment-server-is-defined-for-the-project-or-globally

Answer (score 2):

Try this too:

1. Right click project -> Properties -> Run.
2. Change Server to the one you want to use.