# No suitable Deployment Server is defined for the project or globally

Tags: java, netbeans, server, debian

I have tried to resolve the problem by this questions: [Netbeans 11.2: No suitable Deployment Server is defined for the project or globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60047440/netbeans-11-2-no-suitable-deployment-server-is-defined-for-the-project-or-globa), but my `nb-configuration.xml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-shared-configuration>
    <!--
This file contains additional configuration written by modules in the NetBeans IDE.
The configuration is intended to be shared among all the users of project and
therefore it is assumed to be part of version control checkout.
Without this configuration present, some functionality in the IDE may be limited or fail altogether.
-->
    <properties xmlns="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/maven-properties-data/1">
        <!--
Properties that influence various parts of the IDE, especially code formatting and the like. 
You can copy and paste the single properties, into the pom.xml file and the IDE will pick them up.
That way multiple projects can share the same settings (useful for formatting rules for example).
Any value defined here will override the pom.xml file value but is only applicable to the current project.
-->
        <org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_j2eeVersion>1.8-web</org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_j2eeVersion>
        <org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server>gfv5ee8</org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server>
        <netbeans.hint.jdkPlatform>JDK 1.8</netbeans.hint.jdkPlatform>
        <org-netbeans-modules-maven-jaxws.rest_2e_config_2e_type>ide</org-netbeans-modules-maven-jaxws.rest_2e_config_2e_type>
    </properties>
</project-shared-configuration>
```

So I have `netbeans_2e_hint_2e_j2eeVersion` set to **1.8-web** and
`netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server` set to **gfv5ee8** as is in the answer. But still error of no suitable server deployment. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Right click project -> Properties -> Run.
2. Change Server to the one you want to use.